# First request times out in postgresql using EF core

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Recently migrated from MSSQL to Postgre. For some reason 1st query request now takes a lot of time and times out. Then every following requests are being processed as per usual. If no requests are being sent to DB for ~5 minutes, then timeout for following request happens again.

I have tried different EF queries, so it's not like only specific query times it out.

DbContext configuration

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                npgslOptions => npgslOptions.MigrationsHistoryTable("__efmigrationshistory", Constants.DB_SCHEMA)
                                            .EnableRetryOnFailure()
                ) production
            .EnableDetailedErrors(true)
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true)
            .ReplaceService<IHistoryRepository, LoweredCaseMigrationHistoryRepository>()
            .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention());
```

Connection string

```
"Host=hostname.domain.local;Port=5432;Database=DatabaseName;Username=usrn;Password=pwd;"
```

Error received

> 2022-06-08 11:37:54.670 +03:00 [ERR] An error occurred using the connection to database 'DbName' on server ''.
> 2022-06-08 11:37:54.697 +03:00 [INF] A transient exception occurred during execution. The operation will be retried after 0ms.

```
System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at Npgsql.Util.NpgsqlTimeout.Check()
   at Npgsql.Util.NpgsqlTimeout.CheckAndGetTimeLeft()
   at Npgsql.Util.NpgsqlTimeout.CheckAndApply(NpgsqlConnector connector)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|191_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<Get>g__RentAsync|28_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass33_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

Comment: This is unlikely to be related to EF, Npgsql or .NET. Try connecting to the same PG server from the same client machine with psql (the PG command-line tool), there may be a firewall or some network issue.